# Handlebars retrieve object value in which the key will be present in another object

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

There will be 2 json, one will contain the constant json other will have the original values. Consider this for eg,

```
{
  constant : {address: "location"},
  data : {location : "india"}
}
```

constant and data are the two json object.

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">
     {{data.[constant.address]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

It is not retrieving the expected value 'india'. {{constant.address}} is returing 'location' and {{data.location}} is returning 'india'. I am not sure about this behaviour, any explanation about this behaviour is really helpful. Anyhow i can achieve this with the help of below helper function.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getKey', function(object, key){
    return object[key];
});
```

In handlebars,

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">
     {{getKey data constant.address}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, 'india' is getting printed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebars.js - Access object value with a variable key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646244/handlebars-js-access-object-value-with-a-variable-key)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the '.' operator after data when you are passing a variable key, simply use [] brackets. Like this :

```
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="body">
        {{data[constant.address]}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Error(s): Error: Parse error on line 4: ....[location]}} {{data[constant.addres ----------------------^ Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID' 
Got this error on trying without doubts {{data[constant.address]}}

Comment: Although using [ ] brackets like this - ' data[constant.address] ' works perfectly in javascript (you can try it in console), but it doesn't work inside handlebars template.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636426/expecting-id-string-number-boolean-undefined-null-data-got